# Optimization problem for finding long trajectories in the 3n+1 problem

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, simulation, collatz-conjecture

[Hill Climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) and [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) is an optimization technique that can be used to find the shortest route in the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). I.e. it can minimize the length of a route through all cities by performing thermodynamical processes like heating or cooling to avoid getting stuck inside a local optima.

What if we look the other way around, and want to find the longest route, can one use the same optimization technique or are there any other techniques available? The reason I am asking this, is if we can use it to search for maximum trajectory points in the Collatz Conjecture. For example if it is possible, we could find $n=27$ to be the longest trajectory between $0$ and $54$ by not bruceforce, but by something like simulated annealing or the former.

The Collatz Conjecture asks wether the function $f(n)=3n+1 \quad\text{if $n$ is odd} \quad\text{or} \quad n/2 \quad \text{if $n$ is even}$ always reaches $1$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ when the function is iterated a finite number of times.

Is there a way to find the longest route or longest trajectory by using optimization techniques especially in the work of the Collatz Conjecture, or do we not have enough information about the factorization of the numbers and randomness in the party vectors? Or can we make a computer model that does this, or does a computer model allready exist?

Comment: The only thing coming to mind right now is to start with a random number, start going backwards, and check the modulo base of the numbers you find to see if they're projected to shrink. Trajectories with smaller numbers tend to connect to more numbers (the 27 path seems longer than the paths of other numbers in the thousands, but I could be wrong).

Comment: @GriffonTheorist697 Hm. Interesting. I kind of understand some of the ideas that you propose. The connections you talk about is something that one could look at. Having some kind of a framework that is. I would be interested in a more elaborate answer if you have one. $54$ has actually one more iterate than $27$, but $27$ is so interesting because it makes such a big hop from the previous $n=25$ which only took $23$ iterates, and $27$ took $111$ iterates. ref. https://oeis.org/A006577/list . I would love to see a more comprehensive list of this, for example inside of a plot or something else.

Comment: I am unsure if that qualifies as an answer to the question because it is not making a small change to make it more efficient and instead is guessing if this tree is good, if not try some other tree. I thought in some ways that would be better than start with n and go up to b because a lot of numbers are packed in the same trajectories.
I realized 54 is 27's multiple, I have more or less ignored even numbers. I am aware this has the weakness of being an oversight and I am sure it will haunt me later.

Comment: I already have code that can calculate the total stopping times of some series up to n, but since it was written in java, my computer struggles once it gets up into the millions and after that I worry the modulo operator will stop working at some point... You can download the .csv file if you want to: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f72OmQ5YCp2mLViZQo8FAOceJ1kMIpzU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: nice. thank you so much.